# Why do we not receive reputation by accepting a self-answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, self-answer

Normally, when a user accepts an answer, he/she gets +2 reputation and the answerer gets +15 reputation.

My question is why is this rule not applied to accepted self-answers?

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Because it is `SELF` answer..!!!
If we get reputation for our self answers then this is the first step to increase `Spam` some users(spammers) ask the question which they already know the answer and then they answer their question and accept it so that the reputation can be gained easily.

Comment: @dh47: Do you know any official link which match with your statement.

Comment: @dh47 this is just a discussion, the OP isn't suggesting to change the current behavior.

Comment: I didn't understand why people is downvoting this. What is wrong with this question?

Comment: Downvotes because of duplicate question or simply put members disagree with your point. There can n number of reasons for DV.

Answer (score 8):

By allowing people to self award rep in any way you give an incentive to abuse the system. It encourages people to ask questions with the goal of self answering. It biases them to prefer their own answer even if they get another, more suitable one.

And even if they will eventually be dealt with, it does incentivise the posting of garbage questions and answers for the sake of rep. People don't need those questions added to their queues.

By contrast, the potential gain of just allowing people to get more rep is not very useful. Especially when you consider how often people generally accept their own answers right now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a SE moderator or staff member so this is not an official answer, but I assume that gaining reputation by self-accepting answers would just be too easy to game. If this were possible you'd see users just posting nonsense questions with nonsense answers for the sole purpose of gaining reputation.

Comment: For nonsense questions and answers we have downvote and flagging system. So its not easy gaining reputation by doing so.

Comment: @serenesat it would just be an extra overhead on the self-moderation efforts - some users will try to do this, and others will have to downvote, close vote or flag these questions and answers. It would be a non-productive waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

People would start spamming questions for this .
even with the downvote and flagging system, imagine the drag to do that

Comment: can't comment on other's answers when my rep is less than 5 @David

Comment: @David thank you for the guidance

Comment: This is duplicate answer to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260566/152859) just with bit different wording.

Comment: @ShadowWizard just noticed they are similar, thank you for pointing this out, should read answers before posting anything